# White Screen in Slide-out on click back button

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an app developed with Ionic.

In navigation, when I click to go foward, the slide-in animation runs OK.
But, when I click on back button, the slide-out animation shows a blank screen before shows the back-page.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As you do not provide many info on your project structure, I can only assume that you are not using

Provide more info if you expect people to reply such as :
- HTML pages structure
- ui routeur conf